# Reset seed (to one with unknown value) in R - problem in fast processed loops

Tags: r, random, random-seed

I need to reset a random seed multiple times in a loop, because I have to call a function that will draw a particular value with a dedicated seed (not shown in my example). The suggested solution to set a seed with an unknown value has been to call "rm(.Random.seed, envir=globalenv())". However, it actually causes that the same seed is set because the loop is processed so fast that the globalenv() returns the same value for multiple consecutive iterations of the loop.

In the code below, I am calling rm(.Random.seed, envir=globalenv()) each loop iteration. As can be seen, in the 100,000 random draws out of a pool of 1:100,000 integers, only 14,522 unique numbers are drawn. In contrast, if one were to sample 100,000 draws directly out of 100,000 with replacement, more than 63,000 unique values are drawn. The difference is due to rm(.Random.seed, envir=globalenv()) returning the same seed too many time because the loop is processed too fast.

```r
#Desired Code
T= 100000
values = vector(length = T)

for(i in 1:T) {
 values[i] = sample(1:T,1, replace = TRUE)
 #some function that calls a seed and needs to be randomly reset to a new seed afterwards
  rm(.Random.seed, envir=globalenv())
}

length(unique(values))
[1] 14522

#counterfactual
length(unique(sample(1:T,T, replace = TRUE)))
[1] 63189
```

If I were able to reset a seed (assign a new unknown seed for each iteration), the number of unique values would be similar to the counterfactual number  ~63,000

Comment: I am not sure if I understand you correctly but if you don't set a seed at all you'll still get same `length(unique(values))` which is also true if you set `set.seed(i)` in the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to have two RNGs.  One sits outside your loop and provides a stream of pseudo-random numbers.  That outer RNG is only seeded once at the start of your program.

You have a second RNG inside your loop, which takes its seed from the outer RNG, not the `globalenv` variable.

I don't know R, so here is some pseudocode to show the concept:

```
RNG outerRNG(seed = globalenv)

loop
  RNG innerRNG(seed = outerRNG.next())
  do_loop_stuff()
endloop
```

Look at the RNG documentation to check how many numbers it produces before it starts repeating.  You may want to take steps to stop it repeating its sequence if that is important to you.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach doesn't work because,
as stated in the `Random` documentation entry:

> Initially, there is no seed; a new one is created from the current time and the process ID when one is required.
>   Hence different sessions will give different simulation results, by default.

So if the iterations are indeed fast,
the seed will naturally be the same for many iterations if you simply remove it each time.

You can't depend on R's default behavior,
because it is made to have different seeds for different *sessions*,
so you'll have to fill `values` before the loop or something similar.